# Calculate a total from numbers produced by a for loop (running total)

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

My assignment is to calculate how much money a person would get if his salary started at 1 cent per day and doubled every day.

```
days = int(input("How many days will you work for pennies a day?"))
total_amount = ((2 ** (days - 1)) / 100)
print("Days Worked | Amount Earned That Day")
for num in range(days):
    total_amount = format((2 ** (num) / 100), ',.2f')
    print(num + 1, "|", "$", total_amount)
```

If I enter 15 for days, I can see the salary on each day, but I need the total amount earned over the 15 days.

Comment: `total_salary = 2^days - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the total amount earned over the 15 days

As a standard `for` loop example you want summation over each iteration. To achieve this, you initialize variable (`total_accumulated` in this case) with 0 and then add to this variable each intermediate result from each iteration, after loop is complete you print out final accumulated result like so (minimal editing of your original code):

```
days = int(input("How many days will you work for pennies a day?"))
total_amount = ((2 ** (days - 1)) / 100)
total_accumulated = 0
print("Days Worked | Amount Earned That Day")
for num in range(days):
    current_pay = (2 ** (num) / 100)
    total_accumulated += current_pay
    total_amount = format(current_pay, ',.2f')
    print(num + 1, "|", "$", total_amount)
print("Total accumulated:", str(total_accumulated))
```

As noted in comment to your question by @NiVeR this can be calculated directly, and this answer is aimed only at example with loops since this looks like classic case of exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of today salary and previous day salary. previous to calculate today salary and today salary to calculate total

```
init_sal = .01
total = 0
today_sal = 0
days = int(input("How many days will you work for pennies a day?"))

for x in range(1, days+1):
    if x == 1:
        today_sal = init_sal
        prev_sal = today_sal
    else:
        today_sal = prev_sal * 2
        prev_sal = today_sal
     total += today_sal
     print ('$', today_sal)

print (total)
```